# Showing records that has higher value than one specific record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find the list of names with higher values than one of the other names. I know how to show just the ones higher than a certain value, but I have no idea how to connect that to the name.

**That's what I have right now and it is not working**

```
SELECT t1.Value, t2.Name
FROM dbo.Table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN    dbo.Table2 t2
ON t1.Id_name = t2.Id_name
WHERE t1.Value > (SELECT t1.Value FROM dbo.Table1 WHERE t2.Name = '@Name')
```

**This is something I wish to get**

NameWanted = 3 and so:

Name1 4

Name2 5

Name3 4

Name4 4

...

The one column in common Table 1 and Table 2 have is the Id_name

**What worked for me is the following solution:**

```
with cte as (
    SELECT t1.ID_Name, t1.Name, t2.Value, t2.ID_Value
    FROM dbo.Table2 t2
         JOIN dbo.Table1 t1 ON t1.ID_Name = t2.ID_Name)
SELECT cte1.Value, cte1.Name
FROM cte cte1
GROUP BY cte1.Value, cte1.Name
HAVING cte1.Value>(SELECT MAX(cte2.Value) FROM cte cte2 WHERE cte2.Name ='@Name' AND cte1.ID_Value = cte2.ID_Value)
```

Comment: Sorry, but nothing has worked for me yet

Comment: What's result? And what initial data?

Comment: Check the edit of my input, the result is this error message:  "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

I am sorry if I'm not clear enough in certain matters, I am very new to do this

Comment: This error can't be when you use left join. See the second answer to your question.

Comment: Maupken, please try my new query

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much for your time and patience :)

Comment: You are welcome), but the next time attach all samples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

```
with cte as
    (
     select T1.Name,T1.NameId,T2.Value from T1 join T2
     on T1.NameId=T2.NameId 
    )

select Name,Value from cte cte1
where cte1.Value>(select max(cte2.Value) from cte cte2 where cte2.Name=@name)
```

Comment: Maupken, do you try query?

Comment: Table with names doesn't have any values to it, just names and IDs

Answer (score 0):

This addresses the original version of the question.

You can use a subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.value > (select t2.value from t t2 where t2.name = @name);
```

I originally assumed that `name` is unique in the table.  If not, you can use aggregation:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.value > (select max(t2.value) from t t2 where t2.name = @name);
```

or `all`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.value > all (select t2.value from t t2 where t2.name = @name);
```

Comment: Doesn't work sadly, as I need to show more than one row

Comment: @Maupken . . . Huh?  This shows all rows that that a larger value.

Comment: That's the error message I am getting. Most likely that's the correct way to do it, but I try to figure out how to get rid of this message. "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

Comment: Still doen't work, only one of the tables contains values

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this

```
;with name_cte as (
    SELECT t2.Id_name, t2.[Name], t1.[Value]
    FROM dbo.Table1 t1 
         join dbo.Table2 on t1.Id_name = c.Id_name
    WHERE t2.[Name] = '@Name')
SELECT t1.[Value], c.[Name]
FROM dbo.Table1 t1 
     LEFT JOIN name_cte c on t1.Id_name = c.Id_name
WHERE t1.[Value] > c.[Value];
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work sadly, T1 columns are Name and Name ID, T2 are Name ID, Value, Value ID

Comment: Your query in the question references T1.value FROM dbo.Table1 t1.  That doesn't exist?

Comment: Oh, sorry, just one of those Tables have Values, other doesn't

Comment: I updated but the code should be updated in the question